# Does ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection in different models use same connection pool?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I use Rails 4.
I have main database, configured in database.yml
And I have few models, which must to connect to another database.
It looks like

```
class Model1 < ActiveRecord::Base
    establish_connection {host: ..., ..., pool: 50 }
end
class Model2 < ActiveRecord::Base
    establish_connection {host: ..., ..., pool: 50 }
end
class Model3 < ActiveRecord::Base
    establish_connection {host: ..., ..., pool: 50 }
end
```

Does these 3 models use same pool of 50 connections or every model creates its own pool and total max connections will be 150 instead of 50?

Answer (score 0):

According to [source code](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionHandler/establish_connection), it will be 50 connection per class.

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb, line 128
def self.establish_connection(spec = ENV["DATABASE_URL"])
  resolver = ConnectionSpecification::Resolver.new spec, configurations
  spec = resolver.spec

  unless respond_to?(spec.adapter_method)
    raise AdapterNotFound, "database configuration specifies nonexistent #{spec.config[:adapter]} adapter"
  end

  remove_connection

  # 'name' here will be current class' name, e.g. 'Model1'
  connection_handler.establish_connection name, spec
end

# File activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb, line 532
def establish_connection(owner, spec)
  @class_to_pool.clear
  raise RuntimeError, "Anonymous class is not allowed." unless owner.name
  owner_to_pool[owner.name] = ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool.new(spec)
end
```